# logarithmic inequality with product of logs

Tags: logarithms

Help me solve this inequality
$$\log _{x-2}\left(5x+4\right)\log_{x-2}\left(\frac{5x+4}{x-2}\right)\leq2$$
I'm stuck with the logs multiplication.
Thank you

Comment: Hint: $\log \:_{x-2}\left(\frac{\left(5x+4\right)}{x-2}\right) =\log_{x-2}(5x+4)-\log_{x-2}(x-2)=\cdots$

Comment: Yes, I got that , how do I proceed further

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hint...substitute $$y=\log_{x-2}(5x+4)$$ so that the inequality becomes $$y(y-1)\leq2$$

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions:

$\begin{cases}x-2>0\\ x-2\neq 1 \rightarrow x\in (2,3)\cup (3, \infty)\\ 5x+4>0 \end{cases}$

$\log_{x-2}(5x+4)[\log_{x-2}(5x+4)-\log_{x-2}(x-2)]-2 \leq 0$

$\log_{x-2}(5x+4)[\log_{x-2}(5x+4)-1] -2 \leq 0$

$\log^2(5x+4)-\log_{x-2}(5x+4)-2\leq 0 $

$\log_{x-2}(5x+4)= y $

$y^2 -y -2 \leq 0$

$ (y+1)(y-2)\leq 0$

$ -1 \leq y \leq 2 $

$ -1\leq \log_{x-2}(5x +4)\leq 2 $

$ 1^{o}$

$0< x-2<1, \ \  2<x<3$

$(x-2)^2 \leq 5x+4 \leq (x-2)^{-1}$

$\begin{cases} 5x^2-6x-9\leq 0 \\ x^2-9x\leq 0 \end{cases}$

$ \begin{cases} \frac{3-3\sqrt{6}}{5}\leq x \leq\frac{3+3\sqrt{6}}{5}\\ 0\leq x\leq 9 \end{cases}$

$ x\in \emptyset.$

$ 2^{o}$

$ x-2>1, \ \  x>3$

$ (x-2)^{-1} \leq 5x+4 \leq (x-2)^2 $

$\begin{cases} 5x^2-6x-9\geq 0 \\ x^2-9x\geq 0 \end{cases}$

$ \begin{cases}x\in (-\infty, \frac{3-\sqrt{6}}{5}\rangle \cup \langle\frac{3+\sqrt{6}}{5}, \infty) \\ x\in (-\infty, 0 \rangle \cup \langle 9, \infty)\end{cases}$

$ x \in\langle 9, \infty).$

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).